# how to expand width when overflow auto in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How to expand width when overflow auto in javascript?
I must use flex

[image]

[image]

```css
  #testBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

p {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="testBox">
  <p>
    hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
  </p>

  <p>
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have to use flex?

Comment: @KayAngevare Why not? It is recommended

Comment: I'm asking because I suspect this to be homework related. By asking sally what the reason for the requirement is I hope to figure out in what way I can help or direct sally into the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `width: fit-content` on `p`

```css
#testBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

p {
  background: red;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div id="testBox">
  <p>
    hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
  </p>

  <p>
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: But is it not actually a bug in Chrome?

Comment: `p` pick `width: auto` as default, and `auto` means taking the full horizontal space including the content, this behavior is not correct in Chrome only. Hmm, I'm not sure about Chrome devs' intention on this strange behavior.